# Where to find the sendMessage () method?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse with ADT and I'm following this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
to make an app. But I got stuck at the part where I'm supposed to find a 'sendMessage () method' and create an 'intent' inside it...
But where do I find this sendMessage method?
In layout>activity_main.xml?
In src>app_name>MainActivity.java?

EDIT: So I get where this method thing is, but here's the next question:
Where do I put the 'intent' thingy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In src>app_name>MainActivity.java. Of course, you need to create it.

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Log.w("msg", "user click");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I do have the code-thingy already made, but where do I put the intent? After 'View', 'view' or after the very 'view)' ? Or maybe before 'View'?

Answer (score 0):

A method is always part of the java code part (XML is for interface design, Java is for logic).

So in order to add a method, you have to modify your Java code, always.

Answer (score 0):

In essence you need to match the function name to the function name on the onClick in the XML file. It doesn't matter what this name is (in the tutorial they are calling the method sendMessage). However it is important that the method be a member of the associated activity and have EXACTLY the same signature (return type void, public and parameter View) as indicated.

As the compiler can't check these methods exist (or have the right signature) this usage (refering to the function in the XML) is not generally recommended and most developers prefer to assign their own handlers to buttons at runtime (in which case they are type checked)

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, in Eclipse **CTRL + H**, then in File Search Tab, look for sendMessage method, You will find it wherever may it be in your project.

Comment: Cool, that could be handy once :)

Comment: I can't vote up/down, but I can choose a best answer. That in mind, I cannot (yet) choose yours.

Answer (score 0):

You should create it in the MainActivity.java and after that create an Intent to start an activity called DisplayMessageActivity:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
```

}